# For $f \in K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ then, $(\phi_i^{-1})^*(\phi_i^*(f)) | f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

For $f \in K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ then, $(\phi_i^{-1})^*(\phi_i^*(f)) | f$

Lets consider the dehomogenisation defined by:

$ \phi_i^*: K[x_0,\ldots,x_n] \rightarrow K[x_1,\ldots,x_n] $, such that, $\phi_i^*(f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n):=f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,1,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$

and the homogenisation defined by:

$(\phi_i^{-1})^*:K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\rightarrow K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$, such  that, $(\phi_i^{-1})^*(f)(x_0,\ldots,x_n):=x_i^df(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\ldots,\frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i},\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{x_i})$

Let $f\in K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$, and $p=(p_o,\ldots,p_n)$, then, $$(\phi_i^*)(f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,1,x_{i+1,\ldots,x_n})$$

Let $g=\phi_i^*(f)$, so
$$(\phi_i^{-1})^*(g)(p_o,\ldots,p_n)=p_i^d \cdot g\left(\frac{p_o}{p_i},\ldots,\frac{p_{i-1}}{p_i},\frac{p_{i+1}}{p_i},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{p_i}\right)\\=p_i^d\cdot f\left(\frac{p_o}{p_i},\ldots,\frac{p_{i-1}}{p_i},1,\frac{p_{i+1}}{p_i},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{p_i}\right)$$

But if, $f|g$ there exist some $h$ such that $g=hf$, but I do not see it.

\textbf{EDIT}: I'm taking a course of Hyperelliptic Curves, and those are the introductory thopics, my teacher uses ALGEBRAIC CURVES
An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry WILLIAM FULTON, but they do not defined there. So, by @KReiser comment, if I take $f$ to be homogeneous, then they are equal?. Here a scren shot of my virtual class[image]

Because if $d=$ total degree of $f$

$$p_i^d\cdot f\left(\frac{p_0}{p_i},\ldots,\frac{p_{i-1}}{p_i},1,\frac{p_{i+1}}{p_i},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{p_i}\right)=p_i^d\frac{1}{p_i^d}f(p_0,\ldots,p_n)=f(p_0,\ldots,p_n)$$

Comment: Hint: $h$ is a power of $p_i$. Try an example or two.

Comment: But if I try, $f(x,y,z)=x+y^2+z^3+1$, I get $((\phi_2^{-1})^*)(\phi_2^*)(f)(x,y,z)=xy^2+z^3+2y^3$, and there is some $h(x,y,z)$ such that $$(xy^2+z^3+2y^3)h(x,y,z)=x+y^2+z^3+1$$Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Typically one only does this on homogeneous polynomials. I am so used to seeing this assumption that I did not notice it was missing in your post. Are you sure you don't want that assumption? (Also, what lead you to consider this problem? If you're working out of a text or something, it would be good to add that information to your post in an [edit].)

Comment: The edit has been made.